# For what purpose, some hidden elements are on the Google Search Result Page?

Tags: html, css

I was just inspecting the page with debugging feature, and found these hidden elements. Does anybody know, why these elements are there with display attribute none. First one from left is iframe, rest are text areas

[image: First one from left is iframe, rest are text areas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes, some backend logic and data Management needs some input operations for controlling operations and data. This not belongs to the frontend and presentational layer, so it stay hidden. In conclusion, backgrounds works.

Comment: Nothing like a little handwaving.